# How to calculate a whole amount with fractions?

Tags: fractions

A contractor first completes $7/16$ of a building. Then he completes $1/4$ of it. And finally completes $2/5$th of the remainder of the building. If there is $36$ days left to finish the construction of the building, how many days in total would it take to finish it completely? (The answer is supposed to be $192$ days)

Comment: What have you tried. - Or noticing that you askedhttp://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088590/how-to-calculate-a-distance-with-different-fraction-ratios earlier today: what have your son tried. The method to use is exactly the same.

Comment: When I add the three fractions, it does not get me to where i need to. If I assume all the numerators to be 16, it makes sense but is still doesn't get me the answer that my son's teacher has put.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Find the amount of work remaining

$\frac{7}{16}+\frac{4}{16}+(1-\frac{11}{16})*\frac{2}{5}$